# Can I Use DbContext for creating asp.net identity user tables instead IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to make identity user tables in my asp.net core web API project and I want to make it with code first approach that's why i want to use DbContext as compared to IdentityDbContext. Can I do this? If Yes, then how?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to add identity for your api project. Identity usually exists for web project, and no matter the scenario, I think you need to learn about the authentication feature in asp.net core. You may refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.